# Catch internet connection fail exception in button click

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

How can i catch webclient s attempt when there is no internet on the phone app, because it returns unhandled exception and closes the app.

Comment: Share some code. where you getting exception ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to test network connection in actual windows phone device as windows phone emulator always returns Networkavailable true even if it is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Can you please mark it as answer so that other users who get the same issue can look at it and can get the answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First check for network if available then do which you want otherwise get user friendly message:

```
 if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
 {
   //do something which you want
 }
 else
 {
   MessageBox.Show( "Network is not Available.");
 }
```